# jQuery add text to the markup and remove not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

In jQuery I am adding some text from one form and that the entered text are appending to certain elements. Upto that point its woring fine. But I have placed one remove link with every added element. So when someone clicks the remove button then it will remove the selected element from the markup.

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/p3aqp/)

I have my markup like this

```
<div id="wrap">
      <div id="sortMe">
  <div id="item_4">Test 4</div><div id="item_2">Test 2</div><div id="item_0">Test 0</div><div id="item_3">Test 3</div><div id="item_1">Test 1</div>     </div>
      <table cellspacing="0" class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>
            Attribute: 
            <input type="text" id="attribute_group" class="acomplete ac_input" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="hidden" id="id_attribute_group" name="id_attribute_group">
          </td>
          <td>
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Add" name="addattribute">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </div>
```

and the jQuery goes like this

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.button').on('click', function() {
      var enteredText = jQuery('#attribute_group').val();
      var lastChild = jQuery('#sortMe').find('div:last-child');
      jQuery(lastChild).append().after('<div class="_'+enteredText+'">Feature:'+enteredText+' <a id="_'+enteredText+'" href="#">Remove This</a></div>');
      jQuery('a').on('click', function(){
        console.log(this);
        jQuery(this).remove().parents();
      });
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Here it is adding new div. but it is not removing the selected div when doing click on remove. Its only removing the text. So any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks

Comment: `jQuery(this).parent().remove();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Change

```
jQuery(this).remove().parents();
```

to

```
jQuery(this).closest('div').remove();
```

or

```
jQuery(this).parent().remove();
```

The reason why your code doesn't work is because it doesn't select the parent before removing the element, so if you switch parent and remove you will get the result you are looking for or you can use closest(). Also note that .parents() gets all parents of the selected element, so use parent() instead of parents() if you don't want to use closest()

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3aqp/2/)

Answer (score 1):

it needs to be like:

```
 jQuery(this).parent().remove();
```

because it goes from left to right first selects the parent, then removes it

Answer (score 1):

#### The problem

The problem with the following line of javascript code is, that you just remove the element (in this case, it's the clicked `<a>`) and try to access its parents.

```
jQuery(this).remove().parents();
// You are just removing jquery(this)
```

#### The solution

Just change this line of code to:

```
jQuery(this).parent().remove();
// Now, you are removing just the next parent
```

#### Additional

Also be careful with the difference between jquerys [`.parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) and [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) functions. Don't mix them up!

Comment: @RononDex My aim is not solving his problems. I just gave him an idea  what propably went wrong so he can fix it.

Comment: Yes, looks like a nice answer now! :)

Answer (score 1):

1) Your selector has to be updated:

```
jQuery(this).parent('div').remove();
```

2) Your code is subject to **memory leaks**; you need to unbind your event handler before the element is removed; call `off` before removal or use `one`.

```
jQuery('a').one('click', function(){
   console.log(this);
   jQuery(this).parent('div').remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p3aqp/3/

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
$(this).parent().remove()
```

**[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NewUserFiddle/p3aqp/)**

Answer (score 0):

`jQuery(this).remove().parents();` will remove the `a` tag and query to select the parent div but it is not what you want. You want to remove the parent div so first select the parent div and then only remove that.

So, use this:

```
//jQuery(this).parent(); //to select parent div
jQuery(this).parent().remove(); // to remove the selected parent div
```